Table of contents doesn't display chapter names in memoir class after adding Hebrew as secondary babel language
I wanted to include a few Hebrew characters in the text of a memoir. If I write \usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel} in the preamble though, chapter's no longer have names in the table of contents. They reappear after removing hebrew from the options list.
See the MWE below:
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\part{first}
\chapter{intro}
\chapter{conclusion}
\end{document}

Is there some fix for this? I have no idea what might be happening behind the scenes. Part names work. An article with section names works.
Also, in case it's important, I actually use a couple of other babel languages in the same document, russian and ancient.greek, and I need to use pdfLaTeX rather than one of the Unicode engines. The characters are not all accessible as part of the subset of Hebrew letters available in math mode.

I recommend you try the following usepackage{cjhebrew}.

Thanks I have tried cjhebrew but it produces some suboptimal results in my PDF readers with respect to highlighting and copying... you get a bunch of extra ! in the copy and some irregular highlighting behavior. I also preferred the typeface that babel used. I'd like to continue with babel if possible, or some other approach maybe...

Well the hebrew option redefines lots of commands and that breaks with memoir. If you need only a few letters you can do something like this instead with commands or utf8 chars:
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[NHE8,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
{\fontencoding{NHE8}\selectfont \hebgimel\hebbet\hebalef 
אבג
}
\end{document}



A variation of Ulrike’s answer, which renders Hebrew in the right order:
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[NHE8,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bidi=default, english]{babel}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\part{first}
\chapter{intro}
\chapter{conclusion}

\foreignlanguage{hebrew}{עברית}

\end{document}

